# drop column based on condition pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Could you drop columns based on a condition in Pyspark

The condition that I want to drop a column:

```
df_train.groupby().sum() == 0
```

Here is a quick example in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,2,1],[0,2,8],[0,6,2]]), columns=['a','b', 'c']) 

#remove columns with only zero value
df.loc[:,df.sum(axis=0) != 0 ]
```

If there are multiple ways, which one would be preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood, you want to drop all columns where the sum for that column equal to 0.

You can first calculate sum for each column, then filter the list of columns where `sum = 0` and pass that list to `df.drop()` method:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 2), (-1, 3, -6), (1, 4, 0)], ["col1", "col2", "col3"])

sums = df.select(*[F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).first()

cols_to_dop = [c for c in sums.asDict() if sums[c] == 0]

df = df.drop(*cols_to_dop)

df.show()
#+----+----+
#|col2|col3|
#+----+----+
#|   1|   2|
#|   3|  -6|
#|   4|   0|
#+----+----+
```